# How to get random background colors on a select2 tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I would like to have multiple tags with different colors on a select2.

It can be done with

```
$('#select2Skills').select2({
        tags: true,
        multiple: true,
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Add a skill, a keyword, a sentence.',
        templateSelection: function(d, container) {
                $(container).css({ "background-color": randomHSL() });            
                return d.text;  
        }
});
```

but then each time I enter a new tag, all colors for existing tags are changed.
How do I prevent this ? By adding a attribut “colored” ?

Any help welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the color of existing tags from changing when you add a new tag in Select2 with different colors, you can store the colors of the existing tags and then assign them consistently each time a new tag is added. You can use a data attribute to store the color for each option and then retrieve it when needed.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

// Initialize Select2 with tags and multiple options

```
$('#select2Skills').select2({
    tags: true,
    multiple: true,
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: 'Add a skill, a keyword, a sentence.',
    templateSelection: function (d, container) {
        var color = $(d.element).data('color'); // Retrieve the color from data attribute

        if (!color) {
            color = randomHSL(); // Generate a random color if it doesn't exist
            $(d.element).data('color', color); // Store the color in data attribute
        }

        $(container).css({ "background-color": color });
        return d.text;
    }});
```

In this code:

1. When a new tag is added, it checks if the data attribute data-color exists for that tag. If it does, it retrieves the color from it. If it doesn't, it generates a random color using the randomHSL() function (you may have your own color generation function).
2. The color is then stored in the data-color attribute of the option element so that it can be retrieved and used consistently when rendering the tag.

This way, existing tags will retain their colors, and new tags will be assigned colors as needed without affecting the existing ones.

Comment: Yes. Perfect. Many thnks for the clear explanations on your answer.
I have used `$(d).attr('color')`;  instead of `$(d.element).data('color');` and `$(d).attr('color', color);` instead of `$(d.element).data('color', color);`